# Как сделать без boolean

Tags: java

Не смог решить по-другому. Преподаватель попросил сделать без `boolean`

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] arr = {2,3,5,6,7,9};
        
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {        
            if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) {
                if (first) {
                    stringBuilder.append(arr[i]);
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    stringBuilder.append("," + arr[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuilder);
    }
}
```

Потом переделал на такой вариант, но не понимаю, почему он выдает ошибку.

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {2, 1, 4, 3, 2, -11, 3};
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(arr[i]).append(",");
            }
        }
        stringBuilder.setLength(arr.length - 1);
        System.out.print(stringBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Тогда уж "у брать".

Comment: возможно и так.

Comment: "почему он выдает такую ошибку" - ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что нужно удалить последнюю запятую из строки, для чего нужно использовать длину `StringBuilder`, а не длину входного массива, но при этом в данной реализации следует проверить длину, чтобы она была более 1, так как нет гарантий, что `stringBuilder` будет непустым:

```java
if (stringBuilder.length() > 0)
    stringBuilder.setLength(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
```

или аналогично использовать `StringBuilder::deleteCharAt`

```java
if (stringBuilder.length() > 0)
    stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
```

Альтернативная реализация: найти первый подходящий элемент, и добавить его, а после него добавлять числа с *префиксной* запятой, недостаток такого способа -- повторная проверка одних и тех же условий:

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int i = 0;
while (i < arr.length && arr[i] % 2 == 0) i++; // пропустить все чётные значения
if (i < arr.length) {
    sb.append(arr[i++]);
    for (; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) {
            sb.append(",").append(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

А вообще, для такого рода задач удобно использовать Stream API, чтобы отфильтровать входной массив, оставив нечётные значения,  преобразовать их в строки, и соединить, используя `Collectors::joining`:

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arr)
    .filter(x -> x % 2 != 0)
    .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","))
);
```

Comment: Я крайнее Благодарен, вам!

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант: самый первый элемент сразу *до цикла* добавить в строку. А остальные уже конкатенировать в цикле, начав цикл с 1

Comment: В данном случае не факт, что такой первый элемент будет существовать даже в непустом входном массиве.